# Migrated mailbox to Intermedia. What property causes autodiscover to redirect a mailbox?

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app, autodiscover

I migrated my mailbox to intermedia.  I would like my autodiscover, which is pointing to the old system, to do a OWA CAS redirect.

What exchange properties can I set up to compel exchange autodiscover to redirect me?

[image]

Comment: Was this mailbox in an on premise Exchange server?

Comment: @joeqwerty yes it was on premise

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have to do with your target address field.  For me, local mailboxes are unpopulated and cloud mailboxes have user@ourdomain.mail.onmicrosoft.com.

Comment: For Office365 yes, but for Intermedia Hosted Exchange this would, at minimum, be a different domain, and the issues might be something else entirely.